# Combine insert queries

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I have the following insert queries with different columns using same table:

```
insert into TABLE1(ID,RECORD_ID,V_ID,NUM,V_TYPE,V_Number,table,SP,row)
select '||V_SEQ||'.nextval,b.RECORD_ID,111,1,51,a.CMN,'TABLE3',''||SP||'',b.row
from TABLE2 B join TABLE3 A on B.row=A.row where B.table='TABLE3';
commit;

insert into TABLE1(ID,RECORD_ID,V_ID,NUM,V_TYPE,V_Number,table,SP,row)
select '||V_SEQ||'.nextval,b.RECORD_ID,112,1,51,a.CLN,'TABLE3',''||SP||'',b.row
from TABLE2 B join TABLE3 A on B.row=A.row where B.table='TABLE3';
commit;

insert into TABLE1(ID,RECORD_ID,V_ID,NUM,V_TYPE,V_Number,table,SP,row)
select '||V_SEQ||'.nextval,b.RECORD_ID,113,1,51,a.CLM_TYPE,'TABLE3',''||SP||'',b.row
from TABLE2 B join TABLE3 A on B.row=A.row where B.table='TABLE3';
commit;

insert into TABLE1(ID,RECORD_ID,V_ID,NUM,V_TYPE,V_Number,table,SP,row)
select '||V_SEQ||'.nextval,b.RECORD_ID,114,1,50,a.REV_CNTR,'TABLE3',''||SP||'',b.row
from TABLE2 B join TABLE3 A on B.row=A.row where B.table='TABLE3';
commit;

insert into TABLE1(ID,RECORD_ID,V_ID,NUM,V_TYPE,V_Number,table,SP,row)
select '||V_SEQ||'.nextval,b.RECORD_ID,115,1,50,a.HCPCS_CD,'TABLE3',''||SP||'',b.row
from TABLE2 B join TABLE3 A on B.row=A.row where B.table='TABLE3';
commit;
```

V_ID is dependent on the column I use. Is there a way where I can combine all of it into 1 insert query.

If I don't, I have to execute it 1 by 1 and it scans through the table multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into TABLE1(ID,RECORD_ID,V_ID,NUM,V_TYPE,V_Number,table,SP,row)
    select '||V_SEQ||'.nextval, b.RECORD_ID,
           x.col1, 1, x.col3,
           (case when x.col1 = 111 then a.CMN
                 when x.col1 = 112 then a.CLN
                 when x.col1 = 113 then a.CLM_TYPE
                 when x.col1 = 114 then a.REV_CNTR
                 when x.col1 = 115 then a.HCPCS_CD
            end), 
           'TABLE3', ''||SP||'', b.row
    from TABLE2 B join
         TABLE3 A
         on B.row = A.row CROSS JOIN
         ((select 111 as col1, 51 as col3 from dual) union all
          (select 112 as col1, 51 as col3 from dual) union all
          (select 113 as col1, 51 as col3 from dual) union all
          (select 114 as col1, 50 as col3 from dual) union all
          (select 115 as col1, 50 as col3 from dual)
         ) x         
    where B.table = 'TABLE3';
```